# Prove $C_n(x)$ has at least $2n$ roots

Tags: calculus

Let

$$C_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k \cos(kx)$$ and

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left|a_k \right| < a_n$$

Prove that: $C_n(x)$ has at least $2n$ roots on $[0,2\pi)$.

I have no idea about this problem, can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: There are $n$ trigonometric eigenfunctions and each eigenfunction has at least $2$ roots in $[0, 2 \pi)$ so..

Comment: The first comment doesn't make sense, really. Adding two functions with 2 roots certainly does not always result in a function with 4 roots, for example.

Comment: @Mattos it's also needlessly condescending especially since it references something way beyond calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The condition shows that the last term is 'dominating'. So what can you say about the values of $C_n$ when $nx = j\pi$, $j=0,1,...,2n$ ? And then use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I know how to do it.